# RF Energy Harvesting Project

Tags: rf, antenna, impedance-matching, energy-harvesting

I am presently working on an energy harvesting system using RF signals. I have read some of the other posts made on this topic and have learnt quite a few things. However, I have some questions that I would like answered just to clarify some doubts.

The intention is to acquire 2.4 GHz wi-fi signals from an AP (access point) to an antenna.

That antenna that I am planning to use is either a quarter wave whip antenna (with a ground plane) or a half wavelength dipole antenna tuned to 2.4 GHz. Since its omni-directional, I can expect the gain to be around 3 dBi. I am still unsure about which antenna would be most suitable. According to my theoretical study, a half wavelength is more appropriate as I can acquire more energy but then someone suggested a quarter wavelength is more suitable. Also, does it matter what type of end connection I require, e.g. SMA connection or a BNC? So I would like someone to shed some light on this or maybe link me to a web address so I can do my own research.

Next, assuming I have selected my antenna, I can expect it to have 50 ohm impedance (as this is generally the case). Now, I need to design an impedance matching circuit to ensure max power is obtained. In order to do this, I have to know what load impedance I have on my harvesting circuit. But here is the issue. Since I am designing the harvesting circuit, I actually don't know what the load impedance is. I understand how to design the impedance matching circuit mathematically speaking, however, without knowing the load impedance, I don't know how to work on this. A friend suggested I work on the next part of my harvesting circuit (which is the voltage multiplier circuit) and based on this, I will have a load impedance which I can use to calculate the impedance matching circuit. Once again, I need some assistance on this. Another source suggested I connect up a "dummy load", however, I need to do some more research on this and how it works.

So to summarize,

1) Which antenna is more suitable for this project? A half wavelength dipole antenna or a quarter wavelength whip antenna with a ground plane?

2) What kind of end connection is needed? E.G. SMA?

3) How do I calculate the load impedance in order to calculate the inductor/capacitor value required for the impedance matching circuit?

The circuit that I intend to design is given in the diagram.

[image: http://postimg.org/image/bxaaj3ywt/68b48acb/]

Any tips or ideas I should think about would help. I am still learning. If there are any questions, please let me know.

Regards

Comment: λ/4 is suitable for capturing the signal. You need longer for capturing the energy. All 200mW of it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But doesn't a quarter wavelength half the energy I am capturing as compared to a half-wavelength dipole?

Comment: Do a sanity check first - how much energy do you think you'll be able to recover (or need to recover), and at what range?

Comment: If you have a WiFi adapter that can display dBm (most can with appropriate software) you could attach the antenna and convert that into mW for a rough estimate of power. Although I suspect the answer might come out in the order of nW.

Comment: Very low levels of energy. Using the Friss Equation and the FSPL, I calculated that in the most ideal of cases using 3 dBi gain antennas, At a meter's distance from the Wi-Fi source, an antenna can capture -12 dBm (0.06 mW).

Comment: How much power are you pumping out?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Which antenna is more suitable for this project? A half wavelength
>   dipole antenna or a quarter wavelength whip antenna with a ground
>   plane?

The choice of quarter wave or half wave depends on how good your ground system is.  If you can supply a good solid ground plane then the quarter wave will provide about the same level of performance.  A bigger gain would be with a directional antenna that you could point at the radiation source either actively by phasing it or physically by rotating it.

> 2) What kind of end connection is needed? E.G. SMA?

Whatever fits your design, but SMA is good for high frequency use.

> 3) How do I calculate the load impedance in order to calculate the
>   inductor/capacitor value required for the impedance matching circuit?

If you are designing your own antenna you need a network analyzer to measure your antenna and fine tune the network.  Even if you aren't making your own antenna a network analyzer is the best way to verify your impedance match is correct.

Don't expect to "harvest" much power as you'll be lucky to get miliwatts.  Better off going for a large nearby FM or TV signal than WiFi

Answer (score 1):

You really also want to consider what loading you put on the antenna. If you terminate into a 50 ohm resistor to GND almost all of the acquired energy gets absorbed as heating in the 50 ohm termination!!